# ¿como puedo separar objetos de un arreglo?

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando separar un arreglo de objetos por ejemplo tengo:

```
{opcion:1},
{opcion:2},
{opcion:1},
{opcion:2},
...n
]
```

quiero poder tener dos arreglos:

```
[{opcion:1},{opcion:1}]
[{opcion:2},{opcion:2}]
...n
```

como puedo lograr eso?

Comment: Y qué has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Sera posible ampliar la información de lo que tienes, de donde obtienes los datos y que estas tratando de utilizar para obtener los arreglos..? porque asi como lo pintas pareciera que se puede solucionar con un `for`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es usando [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11)

Donde lo que se realiza en el ejemplo que adjunto es agrupar tu array con varios objetos con el atributo `opcion`.

```js
data = [{"opcion":1}, {"opcion":1}, {"opcion": 2}, {"opcion":2}]

var result = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy("opcion")
    .value();
    
console.log('array con 1s',result['1'], 'array con 2s',result['2']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```